# Symfony - render view by defined status

Tags: php, database, forms, view, twig

I defined status field in my db table like

```
        $newPlay->setStatus(Plays::STATUS_PUBLISHED);
```

that is now saved in that db table.

I need to render a view with fields that have that status.

I made an api call for that but I keep getting an error

> Controller "AppBundle\Website\Controller\PublishedTicketsController::publishedTicketsAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$status" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

This is my api call..

```
    /**
 * @Route("/published-tickets", name="published_tickets")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */

public function publishedTicketsAction(Request $request, $status)
{

    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Plays')->findBy(['status' => $status]);

    return $this->render('@FrontTemplates/pages/published-tickets.html.twig', array(
        'query' => $query,
        'status' => $status
    ));
}
```

Comment: Show route for this controller method. And how you call this api endpoint.

Comment: Updated! everthing works fine when I try to render whole table like ->findAll.. But when I try to difine it by status it trows an error..

Comment: So you have `$status` argument to your controller. What is the value of `$status`? Where it should come from?

Comment: It's defined in my entity.. const STATUS_PUBLISHED = 'PUBLISHED';

Comment: So how can symfony __understand__ that `$status` equals `STATUS_PUBLISHED`, hm?

Comment: Yes it can. It returns all of the table rows, the one with that status and that have no defined status but I need to filter it just to render published...

Comment: You obviously don't understand. You define `$status` as __argument__ to controller. Symfony __does not know__ where to take it's value as there're no typehints and no variables with same name in route.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this..

In my service..

```
    public function publishedTicket()
{
    $query = $this->getPlaysRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t')
        ->where('t.status =:status')
        ->setParameter('status', Plays::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $query;
}
```

and in my controller

```
$playPublish = $this->container->get('publish.tickets')->publishedTicket();

    return $this->render('@FrontTemplates/pages/published-tickets.html.twig', array(
        'playPublish' => $playPublish
    ));
```

this is the part I could't figure out..

> ->setParameter('status', Plays::STATUS_PUBLISHED)